# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security

Below codes are my Spring Boot Test codes.

### application.properties

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=FALSE

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.queries.users-query=select user_name, password_hash, id from users where user_name=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select user_name, 'ADMIN' AS 'role' from users where user_name=?
```

### Spring Boot Security codes

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    
    @Value("{spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;
    
    @Value("{spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

### LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/users/login")
    public String login(LoginForm loginForm) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if((auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            return "users/login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

But Login function is failed and throws the following exception.

```
2018-12-15 16:03:00.821 ERROR 2284 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.    

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [{spring.queries.users-query}]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:751) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:184) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:104) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3367) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3352) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4068) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:400) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:163) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:69) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:50) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:664) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

I can not understand what is the internal error during authenticated. This codes are downloaded from git repository and not modified at all. How can I solve the internal error of login query.

How about these codes?

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/error/**", "/posts", "/posts/view/**", "/users/logout", 
                "/users/register", "/users/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/users/login").failureUrl("/users/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("user_name").passwordParameter("password_hash")
                .and()
                .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
    }
```

Comment: Where are you passing user_name for your queries?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jusermar10 . Please check my updated codes.

Comment: Updated code doesn't provide any information on how you're passing `user_name` for your query. I believe it will be taken from login screen on `login` action. Post the git repo from where you picked up this code

Comment: https://github.com/juliomolinero/blog

Comment: This issue is solved. Please check the updated solution part. Thanks any way.

Comment: Good to hear! Happy coding!

Comment: You mean I would remove one?